# Intent extra EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER in Broadcast Receiver, the format

Tags: android, android-intent

My question is simple what's the format of of Intent extra EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER.
You have sometimes a '+' for all countries ? No spaces no non digit chars ?
You can use this format with '+' to call everywhere ?
Are these formats the only formats number ? 
ex : 1: +141522222
     2: 415222222
I've been searching on internet but couldn't find a satisfying answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the number can change, so you want to normalize it before processing. You can use phone number utils [library](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) or if your target is Lollipop or higher you can use directly [Android Api](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#normalizeNumber(java.lang.String))

Comment: once it's normalized it's one of the two format above ?

Comment: @cilies38 Remember to accept the answer if it's ok for you

Comment: last question for international it's always + or sometimes 01 or 00... before ?

Comment: In my experience I saw several different formats, so it should be + but I wouldn't be surprised to see something different. It's the reason why when you treat phone numbers you can need to normalize the input.

Comment: but if there's no '+' you can't know if it's internationl format.